# Python - Copiar uma celula de um arquivo .xlsx e colar em outro arquivo .xlsx

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas, openpyxl

Vamos imaginar que temos um arquivo chamado : **teste1.xlsx**

Com um valor em uma celula do arquivo, chamada:

**A1 = Maria**

Temos outro arquivo chamado: **teste2.xlsx**.

pretendo copiar nome "*Maria*" que está na posição **A1** do meu arquivo *teste1.xlsx*

e colar na posição **J1** do meu arquivo *teste2.xlsx*

Se ainda ter mais dados abaixo do nome **"Maria"** no arquivo *teste1.xlsx*,
fazer **loop** de copiar de cada celula e colar na coluna **"J"** *linha por linha* no arquivo teste2.xlsx.

Estou iniciando em tratamento de dados!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o slicing `.at[índice, coluna]`

O caminho para isso é:

1. ler as planilhas com pandas
2. copiar o valor da célula de um dataframe para outro
3. salvar os dataframes como planilha

De modo geral seria:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel("teste1.xlsx", sheet_name=0)
df2 = pd.read_excel("teste2.xlsx", sheet_name=0)

df2.at[1, "J"] = df1.at[1, "A"]    # Antes de tentar isso leia notas abaixo

df1.to_excel("output_1.xlsx")  
df2.to_excel("output_2.xlsx")
```

**Notas**:

- antes de copiar os dados, verifique os nomes das colunas. Normalmente, caso não exista ou seja explicitado um nome de coluna,, serão associados nomes como **Unnamed: N** onde N é o número da posição da coluna.
- caso a planilha tenha mais "sheets", tenha certeza de ler corretamente a planilha.
- Leia a documentação relacionada abaixo

**Documentação**:

[pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

[pandas.DataFrame.at](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)

[pandas.DataFrame.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Answer (score 0):

Realmente é mais fácil realizar esse tratamento através de Python. Mas caso não possua o Python instalado ou ainda não tenha tanto conhecimento, é possível utilizar o próprio VBA do Excel para lhe auxiliar nesta tarefa.

Tomando a premissa de que conheça o básico do VBA, vou partir para o código que criei para tentar lhe auxiliar. A seguir a sequência de funcionamento do código desenvolvido:

1. Necessário selecionar a pasta e o arquivo XLSX de origem dos dados (caso nenhum arquivo seja selecionado será apresentada uma mensagem de erro);
2. O código abrirá o arquivo "em *background*" lerá todos os itens na coluna "A" e gravará em variáveis internas do VBA;
3. Necessário selecionar a pasta e o arquivo XLSX de destino dos dados (caso nenhum arquivo seja selecionado será apresentada uma mensagem de erro);
4. O código abrirá o arquivo de forma visível e irá inserir todos os itens na coluna "J" e ao final finalizará a macro.

`Essa parte é responsável por pegar o caminho do arquivo selecionado:

```
Function funOpenFile()
    Dim fDlg As FileDialog
    Dim sArquivo As String
    Set fDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

    With fDlg
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        .Filters.Add "Excel", "*.xlsx", 1
        .InitialFileName = "C:\"
    End With

    If fDlg.Show = -1 Then
        sArquivo = fDlg.SelectedItems(1)
        funOpenFile = sArquivo
    Else
        MsgBox "Nenhum arquivo foi selecionado", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Leitura de arquivo"
    End If
End Function
```

`Essa parte do código é responsável pela leitura das informações do arquivo origem e escrita no arquivo

```
 Public Sub Openfile()
    Dim sCaminho As String, sNome() As String
    Dim sDados As arraylist, sDado As Variant
    Dim oXLApp As New Excel.Application, wb As Object
    Dim iNum As IntegerSet sDados = New arraylist

    sCaminho = funOpenFile

    If sCaminho = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        iNum = 1
    
        Set wb = oXLApp.Workbooks
        oXLApp.Visible = False
        wb.Open (sCaminho)
        oXLApp.Sheets(1).Select
     
        While oXLApp.Application.Cells(iNum, 1).Value <> ""
            sDados.Add (oXLApp.Application.Cells(iNum, 1).Value)
            iNum = iNum + 1
        Wend
    
        wb.Close
    End If

    sCaminho = funOpenFile

    If sCaminho = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        iNum = 1
    
        Set wb = oXLApp.Workbooks
        oXLApp.Visible = True
        wb.Open (sCaminho)
        oXLApp.Sheets(1).Select
     
        For Each sDado In sDados
            oXLApp.Application.Cells(iNum, 10).Value = sDado
            iNum = iNum + 1
        Next sDado 

        wb.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

Espero que isso lhe ajude para customizar uma aplicação que atenda plenamente a sua necessidade.

Comment: Ou usar macros...